# Table data not getting aligned to its width when dynamically added in embedded page

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am developing an application where upon search of member details i dynamically add it to the table.When i run the page separately i am able to form table as per exactly table width size.But, i am embedding this JSP into another through ajax load.When i try to search upon embedding the table data is not adjusting to its width now. I am attaching the screenshot and the code

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('.bxslider').bxSlider();
 
 $("#addmember").click(function(){
  $('#bottomhalf').load("success.jsp");
 });
 
 $("#searchMember").click(function(){
  $('#bottomhalf').load("searchmember.jsp");
 });
 
 $("#addDonation").click(function(){
  $('#bottomhalf').load("addDonation.jsp");
 });
});
```

```html
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Admin Operations</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="home-slider-wrapper">
<ul class="bxslider">
  <li><img src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/images/picto.png" /></li>
  <li><img src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/images/houses.jpg" /></li>
  <li><img src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/images/hillside.jpg" /></li>
</ul>
</div>
<div class="menu">
<ul class="topnav">
  <li><a id="addmember" class="active">Add Member</a></li>
  <li><a id="searchMember">Search Member</a></li>
  <li><a id="addDonation">Add Donation</a></li>
  <ul class="topnav right">
    <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#login">Login</a></li>
  </ul>
</ul>
</div>
<div class="bottomhalf" id="bottomhalf">
 <h1>Admins Operations</h1>
 <h2>In this page you can enroll a new Thalakatti member</h2>
 <h2>Search a member using their Thalakatti ID</h2>
 <h2>Add donation from members towards development of temple</h2>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div class="searchmemberform">
 <label class="searchtitle">Enter Thalakatti Member Id</label>
 <form class="searchmemberbox">
  <input name="memberid" type="text" placeholder="Member Id"> 
 </form>
</div>
<div class="searchmemberfooter">
<input id="membersearch" type="button" value="Search" />
</div>
<!-- <div class="addmembertable"> -->
<table id="familyDetails" style="display:none;" class="table-list" border="0" width="70%"
 cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
 <tbody>
  <tr>
   <th>Name</th>
   <th>Relation</th>
   <th>DOB</th>
   <th>Gender</th>
   <th>Qualification</th>
   <th>Profession</th>
   <th>Phone</th>
   <th>Email</th>
   <th>Address</th>
   <th>Delete</th>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
<!-- </div> -->
</body>
</html>
```

Standlone run success
[image]
[image]

Comment: Can you create a CODEPEN for your case with CSS, HTML, and jQuery codes? There might be something wrong with your data template or CSS file.